# Swift - Cannot figure out the factor of crashes

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

My iOS app (myapp) was finally rejected 5 times.
"Crash" is the reason why it has been rejected 5 times, but I have never reproduced it yet. There must be some kind of difference between my environment and Apple (region setting, language setting, network speed, iOS version and others), so I checked them as much as possible, but it hasn't reproduced yet.
The crash logs from Apple is below.

```
Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x17443a560 :: NSOperation 0x170251b20 (QOS: LEGACY)
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   myapp   0x00000001000df17c   myapp.ViewController.(myFunction (myapp.ViewController) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) (ViewController.swift:0)
1   myapp   0x00000001000d5948   partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@in (ObjectiveC.NSData!, ObjectiveC.NSURLResponse!, ObjectiveC.NSError!)) -> (@out ()) to @callee_owned (@owned ObjectiveC.NSData!, @owned ObjectiveC.NSURLResponse!, @owned ObjectiveC.NSError!) -> (@unowned ()) (ViewController.swift:0)
```

Do you have any ideas?
The main part of the code is below.

```
func myFunc(){
    /*
        networkconditionIsOK ... IJReachability.swift
        https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/IJReachability
    */
    if self.networkConditionIsOK == false{
        return
    }
    let parameter = "q=hello"
    var strData = parameter.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var url = NSURL(string:"https://myserver.php")
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let userPasswordString = "id:pass"
    let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
    let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = parameter.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
        if error == nil {
            var myData:NSString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            /*
                json ... using SwiftyJSON.swift
                https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON
            */
            let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
            let json = JSON(jsonDict)
            if(json["id"].count > 0){
                for i in 0 ..< json["id"].count {
                    let idFromServer = json["id"][i].stringValue
                    println("\(idFromServer)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Even if you don't have any ideas on the code, it would be great to know possible factors which makes reproducing differences (OS, language, device, network and stuff like these).

Comment: It seems like it has something to do with the closure usage in your code. Could you put some portion of your code from this ViewController such that we would be able to help you more on this.

Comment: thanks! I updated my question with a part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your function in order to remove all the potential crashes related to `nil` values.

```
func myFunc(){      
    if self.networkConditionIsOK == false {
        return
    }

    let parameter = "q=hello"
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let userPasswordString = "id:pass"

    if let
        userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
        url = NSURL(string:"https://myserver.php") {
            let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
            let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
            config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
            let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
            var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.HTTPBody = parameter.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
                if let
                    data = data,
                    dict = JSON(data:data)["id"].dictionary
                    where error == nil {
                        for idFromServer in (dict.values.array.map { return $0.string }) {
                            println(idFromServer)
                        }                           
                } else {
                    println(error)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
    }
}
```

Now this function should be crash free. Let me know if it passes the next App Store review, I'm curious.

Comment: Thanks lots! I will refer to your code and fix mine!

Answer (score 0):

I would be very suspicious of this:

```
var url = NSURL(string:"https://myserver.php")
```

Is that some server on your local network? In that case, it won't be on Apple's local network, and not on anyone else's local network.

Or maybe Apple has just tried what happens when you are on a captive network. Install your app on a phone, walk to the next Starbucks and try it. Your assumption that you get a JSON dictionary back when you ask for a JSON dictionary is very, very optimistic. In that Starbucks cafe you instead get HTML that says "Please log in to our Starbucks website to use the free WiFi", and your code is likely to crash.

Comment: Good point! I try the step. I use a cloud server which is installed Linux and apache. The php file is protected by Basic Auth, however, everyone who has the pair of ID/PW can access to the file.